# Use OpenCV in mex function : error after compilation

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex, ubuntu-14.04

I am working on a project developed under matlab, but I had to use C ++ and OpenCV. 
In order to integrate my work with the project, I need to use mex-files. So I installed Matlab 2013 on my computer and gcc 4.4.
I modified the file ~/.matlab/R2013a/mexopts.sh in order to set the right compiler and options for opencv.
This is the output of the compilation in matlab with mex -v

```
 **************************************************************************
  Warning: Neither -compatibleArrayDims nor -largeArrayDims is selected. 
           Using -compatibleArrayDims. In the future, MATLAB will require
           the use of -largeArrayDims and remove the -compatibleArrayDims
           option. For more information, see:
           http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html
**************************************************************************

-> mexopts.sh sourced from directory (DIR = $PREF_DIR)
   FILE = /home/amine/.matlab/R2013a/mexopts.sh
----------------------------------------------------------------
->    MATLAB                = /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a
->    CC                    = gcc-4.4
->    CC flags:
         CFLAGS             = -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
         CDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         COPTIMFLAGS        = -O -DNDEBUG
         CLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm  -lstdc++
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    CXX                   = g++-4.4
->    CXX flags:
         CXXFLAGS           = -D_GNU_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
         CXXDEBUGFLAGS      = -g
         CXXOPTIMFLAGS      = -O -DNDEBUG
         CXXLIBS            = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    FC                    = gfortran
->    FC flags:
         FFLAGS             = -fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer
         FDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         FOPTIMFLAGS        = -O
         FLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    LD                    = g++-4.4
->    Link flags:
         LDFLAGS            = -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so -ltbb -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl  
         LDDEBUGFLAGS       = -g
         LDOPTIMFLAGS       = -O
         LDEXTENSION        = .mexa64
         arguments          = 
->    LDCXX                 = 
->    Link flags:
         LDCXXFLAGS         = 
         LDCXXDEBUGFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXOPTIMFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXEXTENSION     = 
         arguments          = 
----------------------------------------------------------------

-> g++-4.4 -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -D_GNU_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "mxFunction.cpp"

-> g++-4.4 -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -D_GNU_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "verifAndHyp.cpp"

-> g++-4.4 -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -D_GNU_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "../Description/Statistic/statistic.cpp"

-> g++-4.4 -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -D_GNU_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "../Description/Statistic/classes.cpp"

-> g++-4.4 -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -D_GNU_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "../Verification/contradiction.cpp"

-> g++-4.4 -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -D_GNU_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "../HypothesisGeneration/hypothesis.cpp"

-> g++-4.4 -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -D_GNU_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "../Description/HoughTransform/hough.cpp"

-> g++-4.4 -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -D_GNU_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "../Description/HoughTransform/utils.cpp"

-> g++-4.4 -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -D_GNU_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "../Verification/distance.cpp"

-> g++-4.4 -O -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so -ltbb -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl   -o  "mxFunction.mexa64"  mxFunction.o verifAndHyp.o statistic.o classes.o contradiction.o hypothesis.o hough.o utils.o distance.o  -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
```

But when I try to use the mxFunction like this mxFunction('path_to_my_file'), the result is :

```
Invalid MEX-file '/home/amine/Stage2A/stage2a/src/HypothesisGeneration/mxFunction.mexa64': /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4: undefined symbol:
_ZTIN2cv16ParallelLoopBodyE
```

Could you help to resolv this problem ?

PS : I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and Opencv 2.4.8

Comment: Copy all the opencv libraries (.so files) into the folder with the MEX file.

Comment: or add the folder containing the shared libraries to the `PATH` environment variable: `setenv('PATH', ['/usr/local/lib' pathsep() getenv('PATH')])` (or set and export `PATH` from the shell before starting MATLAB)

Comment: @Amro Isn't it `LD_LIBRARY_PATH `?  I haven't used a *nix system in a while... that could be different. Ooops http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/notes/rpath.html

Comment: @chappjc: yes my bad, it's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (Linux) and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (OSX). http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html, http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22999/1177

Comment: Another option is to put the shared libraries somewhere on the existing load library path.

Comment: Yet another option is just to link with the static opencv libraries (if you've built them).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to compile a C/C++ file containing OpenCV code into a MEX-file I strongly recommend that you use `mexOpenCV` instead of `mex`.

Have a look at this site to set it up properly:
http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/opencv-interface.html?refresh=true

It tells you how to install the `visionSupportPackages` which are mandatory to compile OpenCV code into a mex file.